# Notify a socketServer about events happening in the GUI in Java

Tags: java, callback

I have a socketServer accepting connections from clients. Every time a new connection is made, I start a new thread to deal with that connection.

Now, I would like to notify all the clients about an event that happened in the GUI. I have tried using an interface to callback the socketServer, but the server's fields seem to be null.

```
public interface MyInterface {
   void actionPerf (String s);
}

public class FLoorPlan  {
    public MyInterface listener;

    public FloorPlan(MyInterface l) {
       listener = l;
    }
    public FloorPlan(int init) {
    //init the object as part of the GUI

    }
    public void notifyServer() {
        listener.actionPerf("notif");
    }
}
public class ServerNew implements MyInterface {
    public ArrayList<MultiServerThreadRead> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    public String testString;
    public FloorPlan reference;

    public ServerNew() {
      reference = new FloorPlan(this);
    }

    public ServerNew(String s) {
        int portNumber = 8511;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        start2();
    }
    public void start2() throws IOException {
    boolean listening = true; 
    testString = "modified";
    try {
        while (listening) {
           clients.add(new MultiServerThreadRead(serverSocket.accept()));
           clients.get(clients.size() - 1).start();   
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port ");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
    @Override 
    public void actPerf(String s) {
        System.out.println(testString);// prints null
        //notify the clients
    }
}
```

This throws a NullPointerException on listener.actionPerf("notif"), since, I guess, I create two different objects with the constructors, so I added the reference to ServerNew here:

```
public FloorPlan(int init) {
    listener = new ServerNew();
    //init the object as part of the GUI

    }
```

I can trigger events in a ServerNew object, but obviously it's not the right one since the testString field is null when I print it.
I just need a little hint on what is wrong on my design or whether I have a wrong understanding on callbacks and how they work. Thanks!

Comment: @Override 
    public void actPerf() -- should it be public void actionPerf(String) ?

Comment: I typed it in, sorry about that, thank you